# Why do I get this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" in my browser console"

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm trying to implement a Dropzone to upload csv files in my Django project and the Dropzone can't even read the file at all. Receive this error "Not Found: /Reports/from_file/upload/
"

Below is my .view file:

```
def csv_upload_view(request):
    print(request.FILES)
    return HttpResponse('upload')
```

Below is my .url file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . views import (
    create_report_view,
    ReportListView,
    ReportDetailView,
    render_pdf_view,
    UploadTemplateView, csv_upload_view
)

app_name = 'Reports'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ReportListView.as_view(), name='main'),
    path('save/', create_report_view, name='create-report'),
    # Display dropzone.js
    path('from_file/', UploadTemplateView.as_view(), name='from_file'),
    # Process the uploaded csv file
    path('upload/', csv_upload_view, name='upload'),
    path('<pk>/', ReportDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<pk>/pdf/', render_pdf_view, name='pdf'),
]
```

Below is the html file (from_file.html)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block scripts %}
    <script src="{% static 'Reports/upload.js' %}" defer></script>
{% endblock scripts %}

{% block title %}
Upload sales files
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h5>Upload your sales documents</h5>
    <br>
    <form action="upload/" method="POST" class="dropzone dz">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="fallback">
            <input name="file" type="file" multiple>

        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Below is the javascript file:

```
const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value

//Disable auto-discover, otherwise we will some kind of an error that the dropzone is already attached
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false
const myDropzone = new Dropzone('#my-dropzone', {
    url: 'Reports/upload/',
    init: function() {
        this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
            console.log('sending')
            formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrf)
        })
    },
    maxFiles: 3,
    maxFilesize: 3,
    acceptedFiles:'.csv'
})
```

Below is the settings file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    BASE_DIR / 'Sales' / 'static',
    BASE_DIR / 'reports' / 'static',
```

Finally, below is my Main .urls file:

```
"""Report_proj URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Sales.urls', namespace='sales')),
    path('Reports/', include('Reports.urls', namespace='reports')),
    
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Pls I need help on this. I just started this part of the project and I cant go further because of this error

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Does the URL you use for that upload correspond to any URL in your application?

Comment: Yes, I think it does correspond